# Surefire: Difference between suitesAndClasses and classes

Tags: java, surefire

When I run a test in Surefire, what is the difference between

```
<parallel>suitesAndClasses</parallel>
```

and

```
<parallel>classes</parallel>
```

The first example seems to run my test classes in parallel, while the second one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below a simple example to verify that `<parallel>classes</parallel>` works as expected. The check for `<parallel>suitesAndClasses</parallel>` which will execute JUnit test suites and normal JUnit test classes in parallel.

**the test classes**

```
public class ParallelOneTest {

    @Test
    public void testOne() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("ParallelOneTest.testOne()");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("ParallelOneTest.testTwo()");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThree() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("ParallelOneTest.testThree()");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class ParallelTwoTest {

    @Test
    public void testOne() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("ParallelTwoTest.testOne()");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwo() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("ParallelTwoTest.testTwo()");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }

    @Test
    public void testThree() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("ParallelTwoTest.testThree()");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
}
```

All following described test scenarios were executed as `mvn clean compile test`

**normal sequential execution**

Either no configuration of the `maven-surefire-plugin` in the file `pom.xml` or at least no `<parallel>...</parallel>` clause for it.

**sequential output (stripped)**

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.07 sec
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.008 sec
...
[INFO] -------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS      
[INFO] -------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.919s
```

**parallel execution**

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>2</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**parallel output (stripped)**

```
[INFO] parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, ...
...
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.023 sec - in sub.optimal.mavenscratch.ParallelTwoTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 15.023 sec - in sub.optimal.mavenscratch.ParallelOneTest
...
[INFO] -------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS      
[INFO] -------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.770s
```

As you can see in the second example (based on the total time) both test classes where executed in parallel.

For the parallel option `suitesAndClasses` you can configure hwo many classes `<threadCountClasses>` and test suites `threadCountSuites` could be executed in parallel.

Comment: how do you get  <parallel>all</parallel> working? I have some tests I want to run by the method, and other tests I want run with the class.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387080/testng-parallel-classesandmethods-without-xml

Comment: @Will Seems this has been answered in the meantime in your linked SO question.