# TestNG parallel classesAndMethods without XML

Tags: java, automation, testng

I'm trying to have both classes and methods running in parallel.

For example:

**Method Tests**

```
public class MethodTests(){

    @Test(groups = "testMe")
    public void methodTestOne(){
    ...
    }

    @Test(groups = "testMe")
    public void methodTestTwo(){
    ...
    }

}
```

**Class Tests** 
-> Hoping the Test annotation on the class level would do it

```
@Test
public class ClassTests(){

    @Test(groups = "testMe")
    public void classTestOne(){
    ...
    }

    @Test(groups = "testMe")
    public void classTestTwo(){
    ...
    }

}
```

**I've included the surefire-plugin:**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>all</parallel>
                <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
            ...
</plugin>
```

Note: I've also tried **classesAndMethods**

I'm running from the command line like this:

```
mvn clean verify -Dgroups=testMe -Dthreads=3
```

I'm trying to accomplish the classTests run on one thread, and the method tests use a different thread after being complete.

Purpose:
In the beforeClass, I'm setting up the test, and then quickly asserting multiple things on a page, If one fails, I want it to still test the other things on the page.

Where as, if the method tests fail, I need it to completely stop.

I need both scenarios, and I do not want to use any XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I quite understand the use case. But the only combinations of parallelism supported by TestNG are as below

- `tests` - causes @Test methods inside  tags to run in parallel.
- `instances` - Causes @Test methods inside test class instances to run in parallel.
- `classes` - causes test classes to run in parallel
- `methods` - causes multiple @Test methods to run in parallel

I dont remember seeing something called `all`. I think that's applicable only to the JUnit provider for Maven surefire plugin. Please see [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#parallel).

For your scenario as long as you have the `@BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)` it would be executed for all `groups` and it would prevent the test methods that are dependent on the before class to be skipped.

The value that you should be using is `classes`, like this : `<parallel>classes</parallel>`

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.

The provided link you gave was great.  

"TestNG will try to run all your test methods in separate threads, except for methods that depend on each other"